# ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2'

Tags: python, tensorflow, imagenet

I compiled the files with the following command.

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

and as a result compiled into .py files.

However, I received the following error code.

~/Documents/imgmlreport/inception/classification_inception/models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py in ()

```
 20 import tensorflow as tf
 21 from google.protobuf import text_format
---> 22 from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
 23 
 24 

ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2'
```

so i checked utils and i already had a string_int_label_map_pb2.py

why can't import string_int_label_map_pb2.py ?

Comment: I have the same error when trying to run the training job in ML ENGINE.
I followed the complete instructions given on
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: Yup, it definitely works. Follow the complete instructions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a conda environment?

In that case the protoc folder that is pointing is in
C:\Users\xx\anaconda3\envs\xx\Lib\site-packages\protos

You should copy the content of protoc from Models\reserach into this one

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me is as follows:

If you are creating a **Virtual environment**:

Run the command after you create the environment to change the Google file `.protp` to `.py`:

`protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

However, if you are still facing an error, you can simply run the code on a google colab notebook:

**Protos Conversion to Python**
`%%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/TFOD1.x/models/research`

`!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

get the file in protoc folder, then copy it into the >models>research>protoc
And (import step):
Copy the folder to your environment path:

For example:

C:\Users\x04xx18\Anaconda3\envs\tfod1.x\libs\protos

This should fix the error for you!